# Runtime Error(SIGSEGV) in codechef

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am solving a problem https://www.codechef.com/problems/DCGAME/
Inside this, I am not able to find the reason behind getting Runtime Error(SIGSEGV).  On my PC, outputs are fine.  I know the meaning of this error but am still not able to find where I am making the mistake.  My code is below:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  void calc(long long int arr1[],int n,long long int arr2[][n],long long int  game[],int m)
  {
 //printf("Pre process %d %d",n,m);
 int i,j;
 for(i=0;i<n;i++){game[arr1[i]]++;}
 for(i=1;i<n;i++)
 {
       for(j=0;j<=n-i-1;j++)
       {
           if(arr2[i-1][j]>arr1[i+j])
           arr2[i][j]=arr2[i-1][j];
           else
           arr2[i][j]=arr1[i+j];
           game[arr2[i][j]]++;
       }
   }
//for(i=0;i<=m;i++){printf(" %d ",game[i]);}
 }
  int main(){

  int n,m,i,count=0,k;
  char c,p;
  scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
  long long int a[n],b[n][n],max=0;

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
   scanf("%lld",&a[i]);
   if(a[i]>max)max=a[i];
   b[0][i]=a[i];
  }
   long long int game[max+1];
   for(i=0;i<=max;i++)
   game[i]=0;
   calc(a,n,b,game,max);
   while(m--)
  {
   // printf("WHILE-M");
   c=getchar();

   //scanf("%c",&c);
    scanf("%c %d %c",&c,&k,&p);

        switch(c)
        {//printf("SWITCH");
            case '<':
            //printf("CASE <");
            if(k>max){if(p=='D')
                {
                    printf("C");count=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("D");count=0;
                }break;}
            for(i=1;i<k;i++)
            {if(game[i]>0)
            count+=game[i];
            }
            if(count%2==0)
            {
                if(p=='D')
                {
                    printf("C");count=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("D");count=0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(p=='D')
                {
                    printf("D");count=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("C");count=0;
                }
            }
            break;
            case '>':
            //printf("CASE >");
            if(k>max){if(p=='D')
                {
                    printf("C");count=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("D");count=0;
                }break;}
            for(i=k+1;i<=max;i++)
            {if(game[i]>0)
            count+=game[i];
            }
            if(count%2==0)
            {
                if(p=='D')
                {
                    printf("C");count=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("D");count=0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(p=='D')
                {
                    printf("D");count=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("C");count=0;
                }
            }
            break;

            case '=':
            //printf("CASE =");
            if(k>max){if(p=='D')
                {
                    printf("C");count=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("D");count=0;
                }break;}
            count+=game[k];
            if(count%2==0)
            {
                if(p=='D')
                {
                    printf("C");count=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("D");count=0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(p=='D')
                {
                    printf("D");count=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("C");count=0;
                }
            }
            break;
        }


      }
      return 0;

     }
```

Comment: Do you know how large the input for `n` can be? You allocate those arrays on the stack, and if `n` is large a matrix like `b` could easily become larger than the available stack.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i appreciate your answer.if u suggest me some good alternative regarding this would be very helpfull

Comment: @ameyCU that statement c=getchar(); is just to avoid \n(newline) character as input because my inputs are liny by line,hence evry input is follwed by newline character.And character variables are also a type of integer so it wont cause any problem :)

Comment: The problem constraints specify that `n` can be upto `10^6`, which means that the 2-D array `b[n][n]` will certainly cause stack-overflow.

Answer (score 2):

If your algorithm is otherwise correct (I didn't check) but you are running out of stack space, then a short fix is to change `long long int a[n],b[n][n],max=0;` to:

```
long long int *a, (*b)[n], max = 0;
a = malloc(n * sizeof *a);
b = malloc(n * sizeof *b);
```

and also change `long long int game[max+1]; for(i=0;i<=max;i++) game[i]=0;` to:

```
long long int *game = calloc(max+1, sizeof *game);
```

Also you should check for failure, e.g. `if ( !a || !b ) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`. The rest of the code can remain unchanged.

Comment: @Quentin well, OP is doing a timed challenge, so `free()` will slow the program down for no reason. The operating system in this case frees all memory that was allocated by a process when the process exits.

Comment: I doubt three calls to `free` will change anything though.